# How to create an extensible electrical connection with a small form factor?

Tags: connector, plug, clamp

I have a hard time finding a product that suits my needs, and I am wondering if it exists.

I would like to create electrical connections, eight times 100 VAC, i.e. 16 connectors, and I would like to be able to add more later, so that I could have 32, 48, or possibly even more individual connections.

I am thinking of spade connectors that have holes in them on the extensible side, but I am wondering what kind of terminal I should use. It should allow me to secure those connectors tightly, with a bolt or screw or something like that.

Does such a product exist? If not, what are the alternatives?

I know about WAGO clamps and similar products, but I feel I would need to build some kind of strain relief around that.

A small form factor is my main priority. I intend to use ~32AWG wires (0.14 mm²). I intend to run rather small currents, about 30 mA at most.
The use case is wearable electronics, electroluminescent wire specifically.

Small means about 1.5 cm max height, and 1.5 cm maximum width per terminal, preferrably less.

Comment: How much current are you planning on sending through this?  Where will this be installed?  Are you sure the system will be safe without any earth ground connection?  How small is "small form factor"?

Comment: @vir I extended my question.

Comment: Do you mean 1.5 mm width per terminal?  1.5 cm is fairly large.  Is this going to be wire-to-board or a big wire splice?  Does the connection need to be breakable i.e. do you need to be able to easily remove and replace individual wires or be able to unplug the wires from the connection?  Should adding new connections not disturb existing ones?

Comment: @vir I meant 1.5cm is the most I would accept but smaller is always better. Basically I would like to get around (re-)soldering multi-Y-connections. It is essentially wire to wire, but I have a 3D printer, so I could make my own enclosures, but I would like to avoid having to create extensibe strain relief. I almost feel like soldering to a PCB-breadboard plus hot-glue might be a more practical option...

Comment: "100 VAC", "wearable electronics", and "32AWG wires " do not play well together.

Comment: D-subminiature connectors differ in specification (disregard "withstand voltages"). For a higher number off contacts, the shells would need to be oriented "in-line" rather than perpendicular. The number of contacts reduces almost by half if you (can) make one terminal common to all wires.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I opened a chat here, please let us have a word there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142484/appropriate-wire-gauge-for-el-wire

Answer (score 1):

Custom PCB and solder is one of the smaller options, include a pair of NPTH for each wire so you can thread it through for strain relief.  Probably easiest to bus and offset the + and - traces to obtain appropriate IPC-2221 clearances while keeping the pairs of wires close together.  Make the PCBs daisy-chainable with connectors which might work better from a physical configuration perspective vs. having dozens of wires all going into the same board.  Also you could add a per-board on/off switch, fusing, etc.

I very much recommend going up to 30 or 28 AWG teflon- or ETFE-insulated wire (or maybe mPPE if you can find it that small).  It's a good deal more expensive than PVC but the insulation will be much stronger physically (as will the conductor itself) and does not "melt back" when you solder it.  It's also quite a bit thinner than PVC for the same voltage rating, so it might end up thinner than PVC-insulated 32 AWG.

Comment: Hold your horses! I am kind of a newbie, and your response requires me to look up a lot of things. But thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom PCB"? Let alone "daisy-chainable", like to you have any link, or image, where I could see what you are referring to? I am hobbyist, and this is no way close to mass production.